# I need to make a count up timer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a count up timer, it has to be counting the time that a ticket is getting solved even if you change or refresh the page, when it is over the user has to click the button stop, but I have a problem, when it is counting I press the button `Stop and reset` it works but when I refresh my site it is still counting and it doesn't stop.

This is for my site:

```js
var countDownDate = localStorage.getItem('startDate');
if (countDownDate) {
  countDownDate = new Date(countDownDate);
} else {
  countDownDate = new Date();
  localStorage.setItem('startDate', countDownDate);
}
var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = now - countDownDate.getTime();
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
}, 1000);

function Reset() {
  var countDownDate = localStorage.getItem('startDate');
  if (countDownDate == 0, clearInterval(x)) {
    countDownDate = new Date(countDownDate);
  } else {
    countDownDate = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem('startDate', countDownDate);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Reset()">Stop and Reset</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: <p id="demo"></p>

Comment: <button onclick="Reset()">Stop and Reset</button>

Comment: Do not put code into comments. Use [Edit] to add it to your question.

Comment: I'm not too sure about your problem - it seems like the expected behaviour. The countdown timer starts as soon as the page loads. Can you give some more details?